# Passing in func via where clause

Tags: c#

Given a .net 4. collection, if I want to pass in my own custom func in a where clause, how could I do this (via parameters)?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
public IEnumerable<string> FilterNames(Func<string, bool> filter)
{
    return people.Select(person => person.Name)
                 .Where(filter);
}
```

Comment: @Jon-Skeet is it possible to pass a parameter to filter?
public IEnumerable<string> FilterNames(Func<string, bool> filter)
{
var generatedValue = "Foo"
    return people.Select(person => person.Name)
                 .Where(filter(generatedValue));
}

Comment: @TomMcDonough: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve there, but I suspect you want to ask a new question with more details.

Comment: @Jon-Skeet imagine filter parameter being x => !ids.Contains(x.ChildId) and ids happens inside this method on the first line. I think I will have to get ids before and pass in but ideally, if there is a way I will be a very happy man. I can create a new question if easier, this is a generic method.

Comment: @TomMcDonough: It sounds like you really are asking a different question to the one here - so please ask it *as* a new question, taking care to really describe the situation completely.

Comment: @Jon-Skeet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58800268/add-unknown-parameter-to-a-func-inside-a-generic-method