# Add unknown parameter to a Func inside a generic method

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-core

I have looked at many resources online but I think this is something not possible or I am approaching it from the wrong angle.

I am generating a list of ids from a child table and determining if the foreign key id in the parent table contains in the list of child ids. e.g. j => !ids.Contains(j.InvestorId). The code below will not compile as whereFilter can not take a parameter but you can see the effect I would like.

Hopefully, there is a way instead of getting the ids beforehand and passing in an additional parameter to whereFilter.

```
public List<int> ValidateReferentialIntegrity<TChild, TParent>(string childFilePath, 
    string parentFilePath, 
    Func<TParent, int, bool> whereFilter, 
    Func<TParent, int> selector) 
{
    var childList = ReadCsvFile<TChild>(typeof(TChild).Name, childFilePath);
    var parentList = ReadCsvFile<TParent>(typeof(TParent).Name, parentFilePath);

    var ids = childList.Select(s => (int)s.GetId()).ToList();
    var unidentifiableIds = parentList.Where(whereFilter(ids))
        .Select(selector).ToList();
    return unidentifiableIds;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
public List<int> ValidateReferentialIntegrity<TChild, TParent>(string childFilePath, 
    string parentFilePath, 
    Func<TParent, IList<int>, bool> whereFilter,  // <- change #1 is here, IList<int>
    Func<TParent, int> selector) 
{
    var childList = ReadCsvFile<TChild>(typeof(TChild).Name, childFilePath);
    var parentList = ReadCsvFile<TParent>(typeof(TParent).Name, parentFilePath);

    var ids = childList.Select(s => (int)s.GetId()).ToList();
    var unidentifiableIds = parentList
        .Where(p => whereFilter(p, ids))    // <- change #2 is here, pass object to whereFilter
        .Select(selector)
        .ToList();
    return unidentifiableIds;
}
```

And call it like this:

```cs
var list = ValidateReferentialIntegrity<TChild, TParent>(
    "file1.csv", 
    "file2.csv", 
    (TParent parent, IList<int> childIds) => childIds.Contains(parent.InvestorId),
    parent => parent.InvestorId);
```

Comment: what would I pass into the whereFilter parameter though? The values of IList<int> is not known until inside the method @Dmitry

Comment: You dont need to pass real list. Updated my answer.

Comment: It seems that something wrong with my understanding of your parent/child classes, but I hope you got main idea.